# Combination estimation

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, combinations

I am looking at a proof where part of it derives an estimation for the number of combinations and I cant understand how the following step is derived:

$\varepsilon^{-\varepsilon L}\underset{j \leq \varepsilon L}{\sum} \binom{L}{j}\varepsilon^{j} \leq \left(\frac{1+\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^\varepsilon}\right)^L$

where $0\leq j \leq \varepsilon L$.

Comment: What about $\epsilon$? Is real? Is smaller than one but positive?

Comment: yes, $0<\varepsilon< 1, \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is binomial formula $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k$, no more. Your sum has less positive terms, so "$\le $".